# How to get return of InLineKeyboardButton with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, django, telegram

I am working with `python-telegram-bot` building a menu system.

I created a Django project, as shown below, using **Webhook** to connect to Telegram.

I have the button menu built, according to the codes below, but I'm not sure how to interact with the contact when he clicks the button.

Can you help me with this?

view.py

```
import json
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from core.message import proccess


@csrf_exempt
def event(request):
    json_telegram = json.loads(request.body)
    proccess(request, json_telegram)
    return HttpResponse()
```

messages.py

```
import telegram
from bot_webhook.settings import TOKEN
from telegram import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)


def proccess(request, json_telegram):
    msg_options(json_telegram)


def msg_options(json_telegram):
    chat_id = json_telegram['message']['from']['id']
    first_name = json_telegram['message']['from']['first_name']
    last_name = json_telegram['message']['from']['last_name']
    button_list = []
    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Button One', callback_data='query_one'))
    button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Button two', callback_data='query_two'))
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=2))
    bot.send_message(text='Hello {0} {1}!\nI have this options:'.format(first_name, last_name),
                     chat_id=chat_id,
                     reply_markup=reply_markup)


def build_menu(buttons,
               n_cols,
               header_buttons=None,
               footer_buttons=None):
    menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
    if header_buttons:
        menu.insert(0, [header_buttons])
    if footer_buttons:
        menu.append([footer_buttons])
    return menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the `json_telegram` you will get your own `callback_data`, which you sent,  which will comeback like a boomerang

That is the basic principle for Bot programming

Documentation [InlineKeyboardButton](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html)

Comment: I thought there would be a direct call to the method at callback_data. But ok, I understand, it works normally just like other messages. Thanks!